# loop through hierarchical categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with the following data

```
category_id | category_title | category_description                | category_parent
          1 | Shoes          | This category contains shoes        |            NULL
          2 | Nike           | This category contains Nike shoes   |               1
          3 | Adidas         | This category contains Adidas shoes |               1
          4 | Air Max        | This category contains Nike Air Max |               2
```

I want to get all my categories in a nice `<ul>` structure, can you help me?
Now I just coded it static to max. two child-categories like this:

```
<?php
                $categories = $data["categories"];
                $root_categories = null;
                if ($categories) {
                foreach ($categories as $key => $cat) {
                    if ($cat->category_parent == null) {
                        $root_categories[] = $cat;
                        unset($categories[$key]);
                    }
                }
                foreach ($root_categories as $rcat) {
                    foreach ($categories as $key => $cat) {
                        if ($cat->category_parent == $rcat->category_id) {
                            $rcat->childs[] = $cat;
                            unset($categories[$key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach ($root_categories as $rcat) {
                    if ($rcat->childs != null) {
                        foreach ($rcat->childs as $ccat) {
                            foreach ($categories as $key => $cat) {
                                if ($cat->category_parent == $ccat->category_id) {
                                    $ccat->childs[] = $cat;
                                    unset($categories[$key]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($root_categories != null) {
                    echo "<ul class='category-tree'>";
                    foreach ($root_categories as $root_category) {
                        echo "<li>";
                        echo "<span>" . $root_category->category_title . "<div class='cat_btns pull-right'><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-fill' onclick='add_category(" . $root_category->category_id . ", this)'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></a><a href='#' onclick='sel_cat(this)' data-cat='" . $root_category->category_id . "' class='btn btn-success xxv btn-fill'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button></a></div><div class='clearfix'></div></span>";
                        if ($root_category->childs != null) {
                            echo "<ul>";
                            foreach ($root_category->childs as $child_category) {
                                echo "<li>";
                                echo "<span>" . $child_category->category_title . "<div class='cat_btns pull-right'><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-fill' onclick='add_category(" . $child_category->category_id . ", this)'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></a><a href='#' onclick='sel_cat(this)' data-cat='" . $child_category->category_id . "' class='btn btn-success xxv btn-fill'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button></a></div><div class='clearfix'></div></span>";
                                if ($child_category->childs != null) {
                                    echo "<ul>";
                                    foreach ($child_category->childs as $grandchild_category) {
                                        echo "<li><span>" . $grandchild_category->category_title . "<div class='cat_btns pull-right'><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-fill' onclick='add_category(" . $grandchild_category->category_id . ", this)'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></a><a href='#' onclick='sel_cat(this)' data-cat='" . $grandchild_category->category_id . "' class='btn btn-success xxv btn-fill'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button></a></div><div class='clearfix'></div></span></li>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</ul>";
                                }
                                echo "</li>";
                            }
                            echo "</ul>";
                        }
                        echo "</li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: so whats not working properly on what youve done? can you show us the actual output?

Comment: it works, but it's static and i dont know how i could do this dynamic..